# Optimal order fetching Data before or after startActivity intent

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-asynctask

In my code, i have successfully used `AsyncTask`(s) to fetch data, parse and map the `JSON` response to model classes using `Gson`.

***What i do:***
Fetch data from multiple web service(s) methods and depending on the result/response, render UI in my `Activity`.

***Where my question is:***
Two ways to do this, Suppose there are two activities - `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`:

***1.*** Start `ActivityB`, execute related `AsyncTask`(s), render UI.
***User's Experience:*** If the result of the task isn't successful then a custom `dialog` shows a message, the user is taken to the previous activity or remains on the same one for him to either go back or interact with a sliding menu.

***2.*** Inside `ActivityA`, execute an `AsyncTask` to fetch data for `ActivityB`, on the result/response, with  the `startActivity(intent)`, pass the data to `ActivityB`(or save it in `SharedPreferences`) and start `ActivityB`, render UI.
***User's experience***: While the data is being fetched, there's the `progress dialog`, if the result/response is successful, next `Activity` loads else the user is shown a custom `dialog`. The user remains on the same activity.

***What my question is:***
In any way is one of the above two objectively better in terms of performance, optimization  and/or user experience... If so, which one and why?
Also, please suggest if there is a better way to do the same.

*I know this question may not about asking for "one" correct answer, just want to make sure to not lag or lack in quality and performance technically/programatically. We could be missing out a considerable opinion or  (that i don't)know some fact which could help.*

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

I don＇t think use two activities is a good idea.

In your first solution,maybe a beautiful toast , a view just append to your activity or a dialog that will fade out soon will be better,because our users are so lazy that they do not like to move their thumbs.Failed information should disappears automatically.